# how to pass qrcode from .netcore api to angular

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core

From my back end im getting an object which is shown in the screenshot below

[image]

In the angular side how can i convert it to image which is a qrcode,because i don't see any bytes there to convert it,is this object valid to be shown as a qrcode?

on my back end i send data from .netcore which is :

```
  public async  Task<IActionResult> ExecuteAsync(TreydModel treydmodel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string txtQRCode = "morteza";
       var sendPayinResponse=await  sendpaying.SendPayinInitiateRequest(treydmodel);
        QRCodeGenerator _qrCode = new QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCodeData _qrCodeData = _qrCode.CreateQrCode(txtQRCode, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
        QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(_qrCodeData);
        Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
        BitmapToBytesCode(qrCodeImage);
        return new OkObjectResult(qrCodeImage);

    }
    private static Byte[] BitmapToBytesCode(Bitmap image)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the network call instead? You can check that in developer tools

Comment: @CharlieArayaits just a 200 response,should it help?

Comment: No, if you click on the call and check the "Response" tab you would be able to see the raw result. And if you indeed get an Image you should be able to see it in the "Preview" tab as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for. Pls see my code and test result below.

```
<div id="code"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery.qrcode/1.0/jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var test = {
        "flags": 2,
        "frameDimensionsList": [
            "123456789456"
        ],
        "height": 580,
        "horizontatlResolution": 96,
        "palette": {
            "flag": 0,
            "entries":[]
        }
    };
    $('#code').qrcode(JSON.stringify(test)); 
</script>
```

[image]